# querying years that contains multiple fields in oracle db

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i am trying to write a query in oracle db that helps me to select something that contains all 3 data, let me show an example 
Say I have a table

```
ltr year
--------
'a' 2003 
'b' 2003 
'c' 2005
'a' 2003
'a' 2003
'j' 2008
'c' 2003
```

and I want to return the year(s) that contains at least one instance of the letters a, b, c. In here 2003 would be the only year that is returned.

So far I have

```
select distinct year 
from Data
where letter = 'a' or letter = 'b' or letter = 'c';
```

This will return years 2005 as well which isnt correct..
What am I missing? 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the letter you want in your where clause and use `having count(distinct ltr) = 3` to get all years that have all letters at least once.

```
select year
from data
where ltr in ('a','b','c')
group by year
having count(distinct ltr) = 3
```

if you want years that only have letters 'a', 'b', 'c':

```
select year
from data
group by year
having count(case when ltr not in ('a','b','c') then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: Nevermind, this works fine for what I want, I get how to use "having count" now and I can tweak them my own, thank you!